# Django StaticFilesStorage headache

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-settings

First collectstatic was been with `'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.CachedStaticFilesStorage'` it was produce some errors and I was decide to change it to the `'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'` and repeat `collectstatic` After that everything looks good BUT on every few (3-5) page loads page is rendered differently and ask for a `style.d5cb04a85ba7.css`. After few page reloads it ask for a `style.css` again. Why is this happen?

Comment: This is not related to Django's `staticfiles` app. Probably has to do with your static file versioning system which runs separately from `staticfiles`.

Comment: `CachedStaticFilesStorage` uses the django cache-backend to cache the hashed filenames for the files. 

A wild guess would be something related to your cache backend and perhaps having more than one web-server?

Comment: @DenisCornehl yes i use second server to work with static and media files. Does it mean that cache.clear() will do the work?

Comment: perhaps yes, but the interesting question is, why this happens at all